Как найти сумму квадратов элементов словаря?
Подскажите пожалуйста как найти сумму квадратов элементов словаря.
Вроде несложная задача, но никак не получается.
Вот попытки кода:
digits = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4,
}
s = digits.values()
n = list(s)
v = pow(n, 2)
print(v)


Так:
sum(x*x for x in d.values())


Попробовал
digits = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': 3,
'd': 4,
}
sum(x*x for x in digits.values())
print(sum)
Выдаёт такое


@YariorKorsaines, учебник почитай.

Всё, разобрался
